# Extraer subcadena de URL usando Regex en PHP

Tags: php

usando PHP y la función preg_match() estoy tratando de obtener el ID de una url comprendido entre el símbolo SLASH **/** y el final de una cadena que es **.html**

Para este ejemplo tengo una URL (mas bien una cadena) como:

"https://www.dominio.com/Cont/**E0CB24819C**.html"

Entonces deseo únicamente y exclusivamente extraer la subcadena **E0CB24819C**

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: La verdad he intentado construir varias expresiones regulares, pero todas funcionan pésimamente ya que este tema por más que lo he estudiado, no termino de comprenderlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un regex que te podría funcionar es este:

```
([^\/]*).html$
```

Explicación:

- Se hace un grupo de captura: -> ( )
- Con cualquier cosa que no sea un barra -> [^ \ / ]
- Múltiples veces -> *
- Y que acabe en .html -> .html$

Si bien el `^` suele usarse para indicar el inicio de una cadena, cuando se mete dentro de un listado como en este caso indica negación (o ausencia del caracter indicado)

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/u8lIBj/1), tu ID estará en el grupo 1 de la captura.

PS: El `.` en realidad está indicando cualquier símbolo, para que fuese un punto literal debería ser `\.`, pero en este caso funciona igual y así queda un poco más simple

Comment: Creo que funciona muy bien. Sin embargo, como podría hacer para que no se capture también la subcadena "E0CB24819C.html", solo quiero "E0CB24819C"

Comment: Eso está más allá de mi nivel de conocimiento de REGEX, pero qué importa si se captura todo? Ciertamente en el primer *match* tienes todo, incluido el `.html`, pero en el primer grupo de dicho match tienes únicamente el ID que buscas, sin el `.html`. Dices que usas `preg_match()`... según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) puedes obtener el valor del grupo 1 usando la variable `$matches` de dicho método.

Comment: Si lo sé es un array de matches y en la key 1 está el valor como lo requiero.  La verdad son solo "caprichos" para mejorar la expresión, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.